# Trouble extracting data from Json file into an R data frame

Tags: r, json

I have a JSON file that I want to import into R.

Please see the screenshots for reference [image: screenshot 1].

As you can see the data is nested in different subfiles.

The problem is that when extracting the data from the JSON file I get a mixed data table with information in rows that don't belong.

[image: image here]

here is my code:

```
data <- fromJSON("mayo-7996c-export.json")

json_file <- lapply(data, function(x) {
    x[sapply(x, is.null)] <- NA
    unlist(x)
})

df<-as.data.frame(do.call("cbind", json_file))
```

I also get this message error

```
Warning message:
In cbind(channels = c(`1538775970275.users.NqHHgP8hUQOYTkqSCu1WalNEZbC3` = "0",  :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
```

Here is the sample data: dput(head(data))

```
-123.324442142736)), `1580965620278` = list(g = "c25pprxwvd", 
        l = c(46.272837, -119.202105)), `1580967003376` = list(
        g = "c25pprxwvd", l = c(46.272837, -119.202105)), 
    `1580967240856` = list(g = "c25pprxwvd", l = c(46.272837, 
    -119.202105)), `1581011053106` = list(g = "c23p0u442q", 
        l = c(47.6591127532245, -122.308026642539)), `1581012747200` = list(
        g = "c23nb5j99b", l = c(47.6095141701478, -122.336114324036
        )), `1581016826907` = list(g = "c23p0g8c6n", l = c(47.6561938506064, 
    -122.30966473941)), `1581024747917` = list(.priority = "c23p0g84hv", 
        g = "c23p0g84hv", l = c(47.6563152, -122.3105839)), 
    `1581033551685` = list(g = "c23nb4yp3k", l = c(47.6091501116343, 
    -122.335454263027)), `1581038799349` = list(g = "c23nb5sdz1", 
        l = c(47.6124801044895, -122.337269291542)), `1581100481406` = list(
        g = "c23p0ud1jp", l = c(47.6616506030942, -122.307822615892
        )), `1581101479449` = list(g = "c23p0g27h7", l = c(47.6551056142281, 
    -122.310256892219)), `1581105811818` = list(g = "c25pprxwvd", 
        l = c(46.272837, -119.202105)), `1581105931342` = list(
        g = "c25pprxwvd", l = c(46.272837, -119.202105)), 
    `1581106432937` = list(g = "c23p22ptqm", l = c(47.6815923461579, 
    -122.322190813855)), `1581106878382` = list(g = "c23p0g6479", 
        l = c(47.6549642673206, -122.307888697947)), `1581109943285` = list(
        g = "c25pprxwvd", l = c(46.272837, -119.202105)), 
    `1581110531443` = list(g = "c23p2d7315", l = c(47.6932163397294, 
    -122.317267041767)), `1581110855812` = list(g = "c25pprxt4h", 
        l = c(46.2725522962073, -119.20225589975)), `1581126978120` = list(
        g = "c25pprxwvd", l = c(46.272837, -119.202105)), 
    `1581129965670` = list(g = "c25pprxwvd", l = c(46.272837, 
    -119.202105)), `1581277963529` = list(g = "dnnrzbbc18", 
        l = c(35.1165989488931, -80.8692647315726)), `1581278648747` = list(
        g = "dnnrzbbc1b", l = c(35.1165966290032, -80.8692553118908
        )), `1581313976188` = list(g = "c25pprxwvd", l = c(46.272837, 
    -119.202105)), `1581316382332` = list(g = "c25pprxwvd", 
        l = c(46.272837, -119.202105)), `1581317778200` = list(
        g = "c25pprxwvd", l = c(46.272837, -119.202105)), 
    `1581320237207` = list(g = "c25pprxwvd", l = c(46.272837, 
    -119.202105)), `1581320413918` = list(g = "c25pprxwvd", 
        l = c(46.272837, -119.202105)), `1581331518497` = list(
        g = "u281z48n1u", l = c(48.1349044099976, 11.5576956596722
        )), `1581358349287` = list(g = "c23nb5j9z3", l = c(47.6095597765124, 
    -122.335877094208)), `1581359435922` = list(g = "c23nb5j9se", 
        l = c(47.6095308306119, -122.336001621712)), `1581369083560` = list(
        .priority = "9zy4ry5hjt", g = "9zy4ry5hjt", l = c(44.0229307, 
        -92.467567)),
```

Is it clear? please, let me know if I can improve the question

Comment: To improve your question, you can include the output of ``dput(head(data))`` - rather than including screenshots. It will help people reproduce your issue - people can't copy and paste code from screenshots. Thanks.

Comment: Great recommendation! just added a sample of the code. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What you are downloading is called an environment, a list of lists and Data frames. Not a simple list. In RStudio view the environment. Try to find the elements you are interested in. Look to the extreme right for a small square. Click on it. This will create a reference to the items you are interested in. Use that to create a list or Dataframe or whatever you need. Unlist only if you have to.